# How do I print the variable in HTML using Javscipt DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the folowing App returning value to my function:

```js
app.get('/account/balance/:email', function (req, res) {
    console.log('Your remaining balance is: ' + db.get('account').find({email: 'bill@gmail.com'}).value().balance);
    res.send(db.get('account').find({email: 'bill@gmail.com}).value().balance);
});
```

```js
// The function below send and recive request via URL in the function

function balance() {
    var email = 'bill@gmail.com'
    var bal = document.getElementById("RemainingBalance");
    var url = '/account/balance/' + email;

    superagent
        .get(url)
        .end(function(err, res){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
            else{
                console.log(res);
                bal.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(res.body);
            }
        });
}
```

I would like the function to print the value of 'balance' in my html webpage
I can print abalance on console using above code but I cannot print it on html.

HTML Code:

```
    <input type="email" id="balanceEmail" placeholder="email">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-light" name="balance" onclick="balance()" value="Show Balance">
      <div class="" >
        <p id="RemainingBalance"></p>
      </div>
```

Comment: What you're doing will work, assuming `res.body` contains some text and assuming you have an element in the DOM with `id="RemainingBalance."`, and assuming `superagent`'s `end` callback is used when the data is available. You probably don't need `JSON.stringify`, though. But even with it, you'll see something assuming the response isn't blank.

Comment: Please post your HTML code as well.

Comment: trying to add HTML Code

Comment: Please add HTML Code

Comment: Hi, See HTML Code uploaded.

Comment: This program works fine when I use the command <<res.send(db.get('account').value());>> and it will print all records from my database to my web, but when I use the command as per my code, it only displays "null" vlaue.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! I had to input the correct string in res.send();

Its resolved! Thanks guys!

Answer (score -3):

please try to replace this line:

`bal.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(res.body);`

**to**

`document.getElementById("enter_id_name_where_you_wont_to_show_balence").innerHTML = bal;`